# Blackberry WebWorks: wrong height after orientation change

Tags: layout, blackberry, orientation, blackberry-webworks

After rotating my blackberry device (Torch 9860) from landscape to portrait, the height doesn't update. Printing the value of `window.innerHeight` shows that the value doesnt change. sometimes when I reload the app in portrait mode it has the correct height, rotating to landscape works correct.

In the head I defined the viewport like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0">
```

In CSS I defined:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I also tried to set the height (and width) myself in the `window.onorientationchange` listener to screen.height, but this value is larger than the viewport (about 1.5 times).

What am I doing wrong? What can I do so the body always has the screen size?

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually looking for a solution to a similar issue: I’m trying to display an element of 100% of the visual viewport height. My problem is that my viewport height takes into account the address bar (so 100% is 100% but minus the scrollbar height), which I don’t want (since if the user scrolls, the address bar will not be visible, and therefore my element will be too small).

For your problem, I think you just need to remove `"height=device-height"` from your viewport `meta tag` like I dind, since BB devices seem to not compute again this value on orientation change (which looks like a bug to me).

Sorry for my English!